# Removing Lines that: do not contain a comma, or contain more then one comma (in Python)

Tags: python

I'm  a little stuck on this one - I have to remove lines(delete) that do not contain a comma, and remove(delete) lines that have more then one comma. I have to write the script in Python. I have included a sample of the file below:

```
Anarchism,Taoism  
Anarchism,Laozi  
Anarchism,Zhuang Zhou  
brigand  
Anarchism,Diogenes of Sinope  
Anarchism,Cynicism philosophy  
Anarchism,Zeno of Citium  
Anarchism,Stoicism
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: you probably want to use `str.count` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read lines from a file and write the lines with exactly 1 comma to the result file. Say "Anarchism,Taoism
Anarchism,Laozi
Anarchism,Zhuang Zhou
brigand
Anarchism,Diogenes of Sinope
Anarchism,Cynicism philosophy
Anarchism,Zeno of Citium
Anarchism,Stoicisms"
are stored in "test.txt" file.

```
input = open("c:\\test.txt", "r")
output = open("c:\\result.txt", "w")
for line in input:
    if (line.count(",") == 1):
        print (line)
        output.writelines(line)
input.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So you want to keep lines that have exactly one comma

```
>>> lines = """Anarchism,Taoism
... Anarchism,Laozi
... Anarchism,Zhuang Zhou
... brigand
... Anarchism,Diogenes of Sinope
... Anarchism,Cynicism philosophy
... Anarchism,Zeno of Citium
... Anarchism,Stoicism""".split("\n")
>>> [x for x in lines if x.count(",") == 1]
['Anarchism,Taoism', 'Anarchism,Laozi', 'Anarchism,Zhuang Zhou', 'Anarchism,Diogenes of Sinope', 'Anarchism,Cynicism philosophy', 'Anarchism,Zeno of Citium', 'Anarchism,Stoicism']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'((?:[^,^\n]*\,){2,}[^,^\n]+\n)|(?![^,^\n]*\,)(?<=\n)([^,^\n]+\n)|^(?![^,^\n]*\,)([^,^\n]+)|(?![^,^\n]*\,)(?<=\n)([^,^\n]+)$', re.DOTALL)
str = u"Anarchism,Taoism  \nAnarchism,Laozi  \nAnarchism,Zhuang Zhou  \nbrigand  \nAnarchism,Diogenes of Sinope  \nAnarchism,Cynicism philosophy  \nAnarchism,Zeno of Citium  \nAnarchism,Stoicism"
str = re.sub(p,'', str)
print str
```

Output:

```
Anarchism,Taoism  
Anarchism,Laozi  
Anarchism,Zhuang Zhou  
Anarchism,Diogenes of Sinope  
Anarchism,Cynicism philosophy  
Anarchism,Zeno of Citium  
Anarchism,Stoicism
```